# If else statements to check and see if a certain img tag is appended to div wont execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a div called 'ContainterTwo' has either an image with the class 'hd' or 'tl' appended to it, but my if else block never get executed. The images are html img tags inside an array called 'image'. I use a random generator to stimulate a coin flip.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var image = ['<img src="heads.jpg" class="hd" height="50" width="50">', '<img src="tails.jpg" class="tl" height="50" width="50">'];

    $('#flip').on('click', function(){



        var heads = 0;
        var tails = 0;

        var numToFlip = parseInt($('#number').val().trim());

        for(var x = 0; x < numToFlip; x++)
        {
            var ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (1)) + 0;

            $('.ContainerTwo').append(image[ran]);

            if($('.ContainerTwo').hasClass('hd'))
            {
                heads++;
                $('.spOne').html(heads);
                $('.ContainerTwo').empty();
            }
            else if($('.ContainerTwo').hasClass('tl'))
            {
                tails++;
                $('spTwo').html(tails);
                $('.ContainerTwo').empty();
            }

        }


    })


})
```

Comment: use `$('.ContainerTwo').find('img').hasClass('hd')` or `$('.ContainerTwo').find('img').hasClass('tl')` find the class in the img not in the div

Comment: Or, even better, separate data from presentation: `if( ran === 0 ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: FYI: `Math.round(Math.random() * (1)) + 0;` is just `Math.round(Math.random());`

Comment: `$(image[ran])` is also correct. In this case, you don't need your `.ContainerTwo` because you clear it just after append an image inside.

Comment: No reason to add an image to a container, then immediately remove it - probably wont even flicker

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
if($('.ContainerTwo').find('img').hasClass('hd'))
            {
                heads++;
                $('.spOne').html(heads);
                $('.ContainerTwo').empty();
            }
            else if($('.ContainerTwo').find('img').hasClass('tl'))
            {
                tails++;
                $('spTwo').html(tails);
                $('.ContainerTwo').empty();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the random value of variable `ran`.

I have added some code refactor and removed unnecessary variables and moved jQuery variable declarations out of the loop to improve performance.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#flip').on('click', function () {
        var heads = 0,
            tails = 0,
            numToFlip = parseInt($('#number').val().trim()),
            $spOne = $('.spOne'),
            $spTwo = $('spTwo');

        for (var x = 0; x < numToFlip; x++) {
            var ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (1)) + 0;
            (ran === 0) ? $spOne.html(++heads): $spTwo.html(++tails);
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that have been removed the `image` variable because you are doing: `$('.ContainerTwo').append(image[ran]);` and after that you are doing `$('.ContainerTwo').empty();`

Comment: why not `if (ran === 0) ... else ...` - no need for `else if` - you get a head or a tail, check for one, if it isn't that, it's the other

Comment: was @JJJ's suggestion in the question 12 minutes ago :p

Comment: while you're at it, remove `$containerTwo.append(image[ran]);` and the two by `$containerTwo.empty();` ... redundant :p

Comment: @JaromandaX related to `$containerTwo.empty();` I had my doubts because the loop iterates up to the number of the variable numToFlip

Comment: but in each iteration it adds an image and deletes it straight away

Answer (score 0):

You can check if multiple class exists with the `is()` function. You can check all your `.ContainerTwo` class with `each()` and compare with your own variable. Try below

```js
var containerTwo = $('.ContainerTwo img'); //All img in your element
containerTwo.each(function(i,e){           //Check all img in all containerTwo element in page
  if($(this).is('.hd, .tl')){              // If .hd or tl found
     console.log($(this).attr("class"))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ContainerTwo">
  <img class="hd" src="http://img.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/instagram-logo_318-84939.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg"/>
  <img class="tl" src="http://img.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/facebook-logo-bouton_318-84980.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg"/>
<div>
<div class="ContainerTwo">
  <img class="hd" src="http://img.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/instagram-logo_318-84939.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg"/>
  <img class="tl" src="http://img.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/facebook-logo-bouton_318-84980.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg"/>
<div>
```